# Is a non-zero Linear Operator, who's to the power of V's dimension is zero, diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Given a linear Operator $N:V \to V$,that satisfies the following:

- $\exists v \in V$ (non-zero) s.t. for every $n\lt k$, $T^n(v)\neq0$.
- $\forall u\in V$, $T^k(u)=0$

is N diagonalizable?

I was given this question and I tried to approach it using the fact that if a Linear Transformation T has eigenvalues $\lambda$ then for $T^n$ an eigenvalue is $\lambda^n$, but it does not seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You are on the right path, by noticing that if $Tv=\lambda v$ for some $v\neq 0,$ then $T^nv=\lambda^nv.$ Apply the second assumption and you will see that $\lambda=0.$ Assuming that $N$ is diagonalizable implies that $N=0,$ which contradicts the first assumption.